# Android: MyGCMListenerService service force close

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I use `GCM` for notification

But this class not work

> Manifest.xml

```
<service
            android:name=".MyGCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

> MyGCMListenerService.java

```
public class MyGCMListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.i("error", "From: " + from);
        Log.i("error", "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        sendNotification(message);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

> Error Log :

```
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-02 23:11:04.894: E/AndroidRuntime(13626):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks , but this is not my problem

Comment: post your GCM related permissions

Comment: @Maximtoyberman Can you explain more ?

Comment: you need to add some permission     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> replace your_package_name with your package name

Comment: Yes i use this permision

Comment: your message is null ? @MyName

Comment: I comment all class but not work and error : /*String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.i("error", "From: " + from);
        Log.i("error", "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        sendNotification(message);*/

Comment: Can help me ? Thanks